# UK comparability diploma for IT council

Tags: united-kingdom

I am Portuguese and I am also a bachelor of Information Systems.

I would like to make a comparability assessment of my degree to join some university in the UK.

Does anyone have more accurate information on which council is appropriate to contact and ask for more details?

On my research, I found The British Computer Society. Is that one the right council?

**Edit:**

This is the link of a brazilian website giving information about the use of NARIC services or directly with the organization that will avaliate the diploma.

Pay attention to the following sentence:

Portuguese: "Você pode ir diretamente ao órgão que vai validar seu diploma"

English: "You can go directly to the organ that will validate your diploma"

https://www.elondres.com/como-revalidar-diplomas-brasileiros-na-inglaterra/

If you desire, you can translate the text to get a better understanding about what they are saying.

So, as I am trying to localize such a specific IT organ, I found out the https://www.bcs.org/

Comment: Can you add a link to the BCS page that talks about this? I found that they have various exams for certifications but only part of previous qualifications can be used as exemptions.

Comment: I just edited my post. It is https://www.bcs.org/

Answer (score 3):

The [UK NARIC](https://www.naric.org.uk/naric/Default.aspx) is the agency on behalf of the UK government (more specifically, Department of Education) which is responsible in comparing qualifications overseas to that in the UK, on their website they mentioned:

> UK NARIC is the designated United Kingdom national agency for the recognition and comparison of international qualifications and skills. It performs this official function on behalf of the UK Government.

One of their service include [issuing a statement of comparability](https://www.naric.org.uk/naric/individuals/compare%20qualifications/Statement%20of%20Comparability.aspx), which in their words:

> The UK NARIC Statement of Comparability is a document that can be used in support of your international qualifications.
>
> It guides universities, colleges, employers and professional bodies on how your qualifications (including professional qualifications) relate to UK qualifications and certificates.

Comment: Full disclosure: While the answer is written like a promotional material, I am not affiliated with UK NARIC in any way, except that some of my UK tax paid in previous years might go to them in a way or another.

Comment: If I intend to do the process directly to the council, I do not need the NARIC services. It is a company that provides kind of services. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "do the process directly to the council"? I am unaware of what is the norm in Portugal and hence might have misunderstood your question in this case.

Comment: Furthermore, when you say "join some university in the UK", do you mean taking up employment within the university, or studying for a qualification?

Comment: In my search, I saw that I can iniciate the process with NARIC or directly with the council, for example, the British Computer Society. I want to study in the university.

Comment: The UK NARIC is an alternative. But I will try to do the validation directly with an IT council.

Comment: I am unaware that BCS or IET (Institute of Engineering and Technology), the two professional bodies that are licensed to give out Chartered status, actually does a degree comparison service. In fact, the Engineering Council  also points you to NARIC (http://www.engab.org.uk/faq/professional-registration/uk-equivalent-of-my-qualification).

Comment: Are there any difficulties precluding you to ask your prospective university what exactly they require and how can you get that without involving NARIC?

Comment: So, it looks like the UK NARIC is the only way to do it. I am preparing the documents before leave my country. As I learned recently, I can compare the diploma before I choose the university, I prefer to do so.